# Draw a circle of constant size for all zoom levels leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to implement something like [this](http://www.mapsdata.co.uk/how-to-use-mapsdata/) using leaflet.js, where the size of the circle remains the same on varying zoom levels. For example, if I want to depict the populations in different US counties, I would have circles of different radius represent different ranges of populations. They may overlap when zoomed out completely, but once we start zooming in, they tend to separate. So is there a way to do this using leaflet.js. I saw an [issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/344) raised, but I wasn't able to follow if it was fixed or not. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're gonna want to do something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);

var myZoom = {
  start:  map.getZoom(),
  end: map.getZoom()
};

map.on('zoomstart', function(e) {
   myZoom.start = map.getZoom();
});

map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
    myZoom.end = map.getZoom();
    var diff = myZoom.start - myZoom.end;
    if (diff > 0) {
        circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() * 2);
    } else if (diff < 0) {
        circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() / 2);
    }
});
```

What I've done is simply initialize a map and a circle and created event listeners for the `zoomstart` and `zoomend` events.  There's a `myZoom` object that records the zoom levels so you can find out whether or not the final zoom is in or out by simple subtraction.  In the `zoomEnd` listener, you check that and change the circle radius based on whether the difference is greater or lesser than 0. We of course do nothing when it's 0. This is where I leave you to get more sophisticated with your results.  But, I think this demonstrates how to do it.

Comment: It was almost what I wanted. So to keep the radius constant, I made the following changes. 
`if (diff > 0) { circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() * 2); } else if (diff < 0) { circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() / 2); }`

Comment: awesome.  updated above as per your comment.  works well for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help though. I am still new to `JavaScript` :)

Comment: Please don't do this (although it IS cool).  Instead, read the leafletjs docs, discover `circleMarker`, and take the rest of the day off.

Comment: i have lots of circle, how can resize all circle?

Answer (score 41):

For circles, just use `circleMarker` instead of `circle`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker

Comment: @ArunAllamsetty: Perhaps consider if this should be the accepted answer for your question? Shame though as 4m1r's answer was good and thorough, but this is the best approach for your problem.

Comment: Though this answer is more accurate for the library, the answer I chose is pertains more to the implementation which I was looking for back then.

Comment: @aa8y - can you show example code that implements circleMarker in this answer? It seems that the circle diameter varies with different zoom levels: 
var circle = L.circleMarker([lat,long], {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                className: "geoData",
                radius: 10
            }).addTo(map);

Comment: @joonas.fi - did you have example code (see above^) for circleMarker?

Comment: @simplyclimb: circleMarker should stay fixed size during all zoom levels, IIRC. The above code should do just that. And by fixed I mean relative to the screen size. If you want the circle to get smaller or bigger when you zoom in and/or out, then circle is the construct you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you can't use circle markers for some reason:

```js
// Determine the number of meters per pixel based on map zoom and latitude
const zoom = map.getZoom()
const lat = map.getCenter().lat
const metersPerPixel = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(lat * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, zoom)

// Multiply that by a factor based on how large the circle should appear on the screen
const radius = metersPerPixel * desiredRadiusInPixels

// Create the circle
const circle = L.circle(this.map.getCenter(), {radius: radius}))
```

I found the "meters per pixel" formula in this answer:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/127949/106283

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can do like this, by adapting the exponent of the Math.pow() according to your needs

```
mymap.on('zoomend', function (e) {
    var newRadius = Math.pow((20 - mymap.getZoom()), 4);
    myCircle.setRadius(newRadius);
});
```